# Draw vegan graph on ggplot

Tags: r

I am fairly new to `vegan` and `ggplot`, I have drawn a species diversity plot in `vegan`. `Ggplot` has better graph so I was wondering if these codes could be modified to `ggplot` code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using `bray` in `vegan`.

```
library(vegan)
library(mass)
data <- read.table("data.txt", header = T)

attach(data)

rownames(data) <- c("TCI1", "TCI2", "TCI3", "TCII1", "TCII2", "TCII3", "TCIII1", "TCIII2", "TCIII3", "TCIV1", "TCIV2", "TCIV3",
"NCI1", "NCI2", "NCI3", "NCII1", "NCII2", "NCII3", "NCIII1", "NCIII2", "NCIII3", "NCIV1", "NCIV2", "NCIV3","TFI1", "TFI2", "TFI3", "TFII1", "TFII2", "TFII3", "TFIII1", "TFIII2", "TFIII3", "TFIV1", "TFIV2", "TFIV3",
"NFI1", "NFI2", "NFI3", "NFII1", "NFII2", "NFII3", "NFIII1", "NFIII2", "NFIII3", "NFIV1", "NFIV2", "NFIV3")

bcdist <- vegdist(data, "bray")
bcmds <- isoMDS(bcdist, k = 2)
plot(bcmds$points, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
text(bcmds$points, dimnames(data)[[1]])
```

Comment: Can you dput some of the data in data.txt?  Also, is the library mass or MASS?  Finally, does the vegan package create bar plots?

Comment: @lawyeR Thank you for the reply. No it doesnt create a bar plots. It shows , how the weeds are spread in the sites. http://imgur.com/ePOQC3T. Can this kind of graph be drawn on ggplot? I could find a way to attach a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed create a plot that looks like the imgur image.  First I created some made-up data for your weeds.  Then I called `ggplot2` and put the weed names at the points, but made the points transparent.

```
x <- seq(from = -1, to = 1, .025)
df <- data.frame(valuesX = sample(x, size = 48, replace = TRUE),
                 valuesY = sample(x, size = 48, replace = TRUE),
                 seeds = c("TCI1", "TCI2", "TCI3", "TCII1", "TCII2", "TCII3", "TCIII1", "TCIII2", "TCIII3", "TCIV1", "TCIV2", "TCIV3",
                           "NCI1", "NCI2", "NCI3", "NCII1", "NCII2", "NCII3", "NCIII1", "NCIII2", "NCIII3", "NCIV1", "NCIV2", "NCIV3","TFI1", "TFI2", "TFI3", "TFII1", "TFII2", "TFII3", "TFIII1", "TFIII2", "TFIII3", "TFIV1", "TFIV2", "TFIV3",
                           "NFI1", "NFI2", "NFI3", "NFII1", "NFII2", "NFII3", "NFIII1", "NFIII2", "NFIII3", "NFIV1", "NFIV2", "NFIV3")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = valuesX, y = valuesY)) +
  geom_point(colour = "transparent") +
  geom_text(data = df, aes(label = seeds), hjust = 1.5) + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Your axis label", y = "", title = "Weed Distribution") +
  theme(axis.ticks= element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

You can adjust all the elements of the plot as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. But what are the two axis in this graph? What does the x axis and y axis represent? Thank you!

Comment: I made up the data.  What data are you plotting?

Comment: lets say this [data] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoy3v6hae2m1782/bray1.xlsx?dl=0). It has name of the species and their biomass.